# JSF 2 - Required Checkbox

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to write a required checkbox that for terms and conditions that a user must accept. I dont actually need any backing bean I just need to make sure the user checks the box.

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

JSF:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox required="true"> <f:validator validatorId="RequiredCheckboxValidator" /></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Java code:

```
@FacesValidator("RequiredCheckboxValidator")
public class RequiredCheckboxValidator implements Validator {

    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
        throws ValidatorException
    {
        if (value.equals(Boolean.FALSE)) {
            String requiredMessage = ((UIInput) component).getRequiredMessage();

            if (requiredMessage == null) {
                Object label = component.getAttributes().get("label");
                if (label == null || (label instanceof String && ((String) label).length() == 0)) {
                    label = component.getValueExpression("label");
                }
                if (label == null) {
                    label = component.getClientId(context);
                }
                requiredMessage = MessageFormat.format(UIInput.REQUIRED_MESSAGE_ID, label);
            }

            throw new ValidatorException(
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, requiredMessage, requiredMessage));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks to BalusC for the RequiredCheckboxValidator code

Comment: How exactly does it fail? To start, is the `validate()` method hit? By the way, [the OmniFaces one](https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/validators/RequiredCheckboxValidator.xhtml) works for me with `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>`.

Comment: The validate method is definitely called but I need to debug further. It works with h:selectBooleanCheckbox so it is specific to primefaces.